# What's the best way to analyze flying creatures?

Tags: no-mans-sky

In No Man's Sky, some planets have flying creatures. As far as I can tell, it's very difficult or next to impossible to analyze them, leaving me unable to analyze all creatures on a planet.

So, what is the best way to scan and analyze flying creatures?

Comment: I haven't had any difficulty scanning them. Are you zooming in?

Comment: I am. The little fast moving ones are tough to keep in focus, but the bigger creatures even give me trouble.

Comment: One note of caution.  If you're trying to get the reward/milestone for scanning all animals on a planet, it's currently a bit broken (at least on the PS4).  I spent hours tracking down the last one on a particular planet only to have the upload simply not available, no matter how many times I come back and try it.  So my milestone tracker says I've found all animals on 2 planets when in reality I've done so on 3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've found shooting them down is really the best way to scan the little ones (sorry!).

Comment: You're able to analyze a dead creature? I thought they disintegrated into elements before you could do so.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf nope! Give it a try, once you kill it you can run over and scan the corpse.

Comment: I will give it a shot soon then. I'm on an unlucky streak and keep finding planets that have no fauna...

Comment: This worked out pretty well actually, even with a mining laser. Thanks!

Comment: I attacked a flying eel-like creature with homing boltcaster shots, and I swear it took around 500 rounds and it's still flying. Am I missing my shots despite the homing capabilities, or do some creatures just have massive HP pools?

Answer (score 8):

As of [patch 1.07](http://www.no-mans-sky.com/2016/08/ps4-patch-notes-1-07/) it is much easier to tag flying creatures from the ground without having to shoot them down first. You may need to zoom in a little bit when using the scanner, but I can do this unfailingly now.

*(I was never even able to shoot them down before the patch)*

Comment: The patch makes scanning flying creatures much simpler now.

Answer (score 1):

I found that getting to higher ground, or using the jetpack to get closer, helps a bit.